# Codelite can't find sstream

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to compile my project that has a library utilizing sstream using gcc with CodeLite.
But for some reason the compiler can't find sstream
    fatal error :sstream: No such file or directory

CodeLite is using the same installation of gcc as Devc++ and TurboC++, Which have no problem compiling the same code.

Comment: You mean you do `#include <sstream>`? It is a c++ library, not C.

Comment: Instead of compiling with a `gcc` command, try `g++`, `c++`, or `gcc -x c++`. Or find the CodeLite setting for which language is being used and change it. Or, if CodeLite derives the language from your source file name, change it from `something.c` to `something.c++` or `something.cpp`. Note that it is important you learn which programming language you are using and which command is used to compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when asking such questions, its a good idea to also provide the build output from the `Output View -> Build` tab of CodeLite.

Assuming your code is written correctly, I would guess that your file is named `file.c` (change `file` to the real file name here)

By default, CodeLite will invoke `gcc` for `.c` and `g++` for the following file extensions:

- `cpp`
- `.cxx`
- `.cc`
- `.c++`

Make sure your file name extension is set to `cpp` and not `c`

Alternatively (not recommended), you can change CodeLite settings and tell it to invoke `g++` for either `c` or `c++` file.

This can be done from:

`Settings -> Build Settings -> Compilers -> YOUR PROJECT COMPILER -> File Types tab`
You will see there list of file extensions and the compile line using macros. For example for a `c` file this is the  line used by CodeLite:

```
$(CC) $(SourceSwitch) "$(FileFullPath)" $(CFLAGS) $(ObjectSwitch)$(IntermediateDirectory)/$(ObjectName)$(ObjectSuffix) $(IncludePath)
```

You can double click the `c` file entry and change `$(CC)` into `$(CXX)` (or copy the line from the `cpp` entry)

Again, this is not recommended :)

Eran

Comment: Thanks for the info. It turned out that i had somehow messed up my compiler at some point. Ended up reinstalling Mingw and the trying to compile my project with that and it worked fine.